# Mongo update based on array index

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of people in my database, where each person is one document. I would like to give them standard names (this is just for demo purposes – I don't care who gets which name so long as its unique).

I have an array of names to give them but I am not sure how to do this in Mongo. One simple way would be to just have a cursor and update the documents one by one, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

example db:

```
{id: 1234, age: 50}
{id: 1235, age: 40}
{id: 1236, age: 30}
```

Names:

```
['Bob', 'Jill', 'Gina']
```

Desired end state:

```
{id: 1234, age: 50, name: 'Bob'}
{id: 1235, age: 40, name: 'Jill'}
{id: 1236, age: 30, name: 'Gina'}
```

Comment: Could you post some more information like the collection structure, so that we have more clarity on this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are specifying which names go with which `_id`s, so I'm going to assume you have a mapping specified in the following form:

```
> nameMapping
[{ "_id" : 1234, "name" : "Bob" }, { "_id" : 1235, "name" : "Jill" }, { "_id" : 1236, "name" : "Gina" }]
```

Then a good way to update every doc with a name is to use bulk operations. Bulk operations are supported in the drivers but I'll give the example in the mongo shell with [`bulk.find.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#), which is available as of MongoDB 2.6.

```
> var bulk = db.people.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> nameMapping.forEach(function(pair) {
    bulk.find( { "_id" : pair._id } ).update( { $set: { "name" : pair.name } } )
})
> bulk.execute()
```